# How to creat Array in for in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

i have code :

```
>     d=96
>     for i=0:3
>     a=gray(:,i*d+1:d*(i+1));
>     []=a;
>     end
```

when the loop is finished, I will have a variable containing all the values ​​of **"a"**

i don't know how to do

i hope someone will help

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply assign `a` to a variable

```
 res = cell( 1, 4 ); %// pre-allocate
 for ii=0:3
     a = gray( :, ii*d+1:d*(ii+1) );
     res{ii+1} = a; %// assign to a cell array
 end
```

Comment: thank for your reply !!!
i have a question : How to graft all images in array then display in one figure ?

Comment: @hảilong if you have a new question - please post it as a new one.